# Is there a way not to create dependant child images when building a docker container

Tags: docker

When I build my docker image it seems to leave a lot of dependant child images i can not remove. All the one tags with none are have dependent child image  6eec32da1dc3, or the image I built.   They are big. Is there a way to avoid this
[image]

Comment: Are you able to use `docker prune` at all?

Comment: Otherwise it might be helpful to see what your Dockerfile is